# svn diff: Compare my local uncommited changes with an arbitrary version of the file from the repository

Tags: svn, diff

Let's say I've checked out revision 10 of hello.c which is the latest one in the repository. I've made some changes to hello.c locally in my workspace, but I haven't committed it yet. Now, how can I compare this local uncommitted changes made on top of revision 10 with, say, revision 7 of hello.c in the repository?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see how your working copy's modifications to the file `hello.c` compare against revision 7 use:

```
svn diff -r 7 hello.c
```

Comment: Thanks, got it - I was trying `svn diff -r7: hello.c` (7 followed by a colon), and wondering why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

According to: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re09.html

`--revision N`
The client compares TARGET@N against working copy.

So it would be

```
svn diff -r 7 hello.c
```